# Proving that this function must be even

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function that is not identically equal to zero.  Suppose further that $u$ is an odd function (ie. $u(\mathbf{x})=-u(-\mathbf{x})$).  Let $g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  I'd like to prove the following:

If

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u(\mathbf{x})f(g(\mathbf{x}))d\mathbf{x}=0 \qquad \forall f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$$

then $g(\mathbf{x})=g(-\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, that is $g$ is an even function.

Comment: What is $C_b(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I think it is the space of functions with compact support, @user7530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the statement false? Let $B:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an even bump function centered at $0$ of radius 1. Then if
$$u(x) = B(x+1)-B(x-1)$$
and
$$g(x) = B(x-k)$$
for $|k|>3$, then your integral converges and is zero for any $f$, but $g$ is not an even function.

Comment: That's a nice counterxample.  Thanks!